# Vector flow, i.e. a one-parameter diffeomorphism starting with a singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

In Arnold's "Ordinary Differential Equations-MIT Press (1978).pdf", vector flow with initial value at point $x_0$, i.e. solutions of $x'(t) = v(x(t))$. I'm mostly interested in initial value which is a singular point.

In page 13 - 14, it is said that

> In 1-dim flow, $t - t_0 = \int_{x_0}^{\varphi(t)} \frac{d{\xi}}{v(\xi)} $ if $v(x_0) \neq 0$, and $\varphi(t) = x_0$ if $v(x_0) = 0 $.
> When $v(x_0) = 0$, just let $\varphi(t) \equiv x_0$.

In page 51, Corollary 3 says that

> In 2-dim flow, the vector flow $v$ determines a local phase flow in a neighbourhood
> of a nonsingular point $x_0$ ($v(x_0) \neq 0$).

In page 221, corollary says that

> if $v$ is continuously differentiable, given any point $x$
> sufficiently close to $x_0$, there exists a neighborhood of $t_0$ in
> which a solution is defined. (Using Lipschitz condition, Picard approximation and contraction mapping)

My question is that:

1. In corollory 3, when we try to generalize 1-dim vector flow to 2-dim vector flow, why we cannot just let $\varphi(t) \equiv x_0$ for all time t and say that it is a phase flow?
2. In order to prove that In 2-dim flow, the vector flow $v$ determines a local phase flow in a neighbourhood of a singular point $x_0$, i.e. $v(x_0) = 0$, the book uses two chapters of direct product of 1-dim flow and eigenvalues and eigenspaces. Why don't we just use Picard's existence and uniqueness theorem with Lipschitz condition? What's the difference between these two proofs?

Comment: In cor 3 the regular case is characterized where the flow can locally be mapped to parallel lines. The singular or stationary cases where $v(x_0)=0$ give more interesting patterns depending on the Jacobian or higher derivatives of $v$. // I'm not sure if you read that right. The eigenvalues are needed to determine the pattern of the flow around the stationary point. One would need more context.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, but using Lipschitz condition, we can always prove that it is locally a diffeomorphism around a stationary point without looking at eigenvalues.

Comment: A diffeomorphism to what? The Hartman-Grobman theorem and theories around stable/central/unstable manifolds exist for a reason.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, here I don't mean it is topological equivalent to some manifold. What I wanna say is that this equation x'(t) = v(x(t)) is locally a one-parameter diffeomorphism around a stationary point without using the eigenvalues of v(x(0)).

Comment: You understand that the second and third point are about the flow, that is a bunch of solutions and their relations to each other? About archetypes of these relations? One archetype is parallel lines, another is a sink, another concentric circles etc. It there is a stationary point in the domain under consideration, then "parallel lines" is not possible, the selection of the others depends on the eigenvalues.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ok, thank you. So proving diffeomorphism does not require eigenvalue analysis. But pattern and classification of flow near stationary point requires eigenvalue analysis.

Comment: Yes, that the flow $\phi_t$ after fixing $t$ is a diffeomorphism does not depend on the eigenvalues. That a diffeomorphism $h$ exists so that $x=x_0+h(z)$ and $\dot x=v(x)$ is equivalent to $\dot z=Az$ does depend on the eigenvalues (especially that none of them is zero).